# How to Display a value for the dates?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005

Database1

Table1

```
ID Date Status

001 23-02-2009 Worked
001 24-02-2009
001 25-02-2009
001 26-02-2009 Worked
002 24-02-2009 Worked
002 25-02-2009
002 26-02-2009
002 27-02-2009
002 28-02-2009 Worked
```

...,

Database2

Table2

```
ID FromDate ToDate Reason

001 24-02-2009 25-02-2009 ShortLeave
002 25-02-2009 27-02-2009 MedicalLeave
```

...,

Tried Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, 
t1.Date, 
CASE WHEN t2.ID IS NULL THEN t1.Status ELSE 'Leave' END AS Workedtime      
from Database1.dbo.table1 AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Database2.dbo.table2 AS t2 
ON t1.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.ID 
AND t1.Date BETWEEN t2.FromDATE AND t2.ToDATE
```

It should display a Reason from table2 Instead of Leave

Expected Output

ID Date Status

```
001 23-02-2009 Worked
001 24-02-2009 ShortLeave
001 25-02-2009 ShortLeave
001 26-02-2009 Worked
002 24-02-2009 Worked
002 25-02-2009 MedicalLeave
002 26-02-2009 MedicalLeave
002 27-02-2009 MedicalLeave
002 28-02-2009 Worked
```

...,

So It should display a Reason Instead of Leave where table1.id = table2.id and t1.date between t2.fromdate and t2.todate.

How to modify my query?

Need Query Help

Comment: In table 2, should the Id for the second entry be 002?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your own query was almost there, you just need to use the `Reason` column from `Table2` when it's available:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Date, ISNULL(t2.Reason, t1.Status) AS WorkedTime
FROM Table1 AS t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 AS t2
        ON t1.ID COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = t2.ID
            AND t1.Date BETWEEN t2.FromDate AND t2.ToDate
ORDER BY t1.ID, t1.Date
```

Comment: Hmm, sounds like you need the `COLLATE` from your original query. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I already using a COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT, But It showing as same error.

Comment: Perhaps try adding a `COLLATE` to the `ISNULL` clause too: `ISNULL(t2.Reason, t1.Status COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT) AS WorkedTime`